# How can i access the variable "knex1" from the below code from "knexfile.js" file into the the db file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mysql-workbench, knex.js, bookshelf.js

How can i access the variable "knex1" from the below code from "knexfile.js" file into the the "db.js" file to check that whether the connection  within "db.js" is connected or not ,thereby saying console message as "DB Connected"? ... But it says "*TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined*" error when i run?

*knexfile.js*

```
    var knex1 = {
      development: {
        client: 'mysql',
        connection: {
          host: 'localhost',
          user: 'root',
          password: 'password',
          database: 'user_data',
        }
      },
    };

module.exports = knex1;
```

*db.js* file

```
  const mysql = require('mysql');
    const db = require('../knexfile');
    const NODE_ENV = 'development' ;
    const knex = require('knex')((db)[NODE_ENV]);
    const bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

    db.connection.connect(function(err){
    if(!err) {
      console.log("Database is connected ... ");
    }
    else {
      console.log("Error connecting database ... ");
    }
    });


    let registerdata = bookshelf.Model.extend({
      tableName: 'RegisterData'
    });

    module.exports = {
      registerdata
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your directory listing if your db.js and knexfile.js are in same folder like this

```
-db.js
-knexfile.js
```

then use `const db = require('./knexfile');`

if the db.js is inside another folder like this

```
-folder
 -db.js
-knexfile.js
```

then use `const db = require('../knexfile');`

The `../` or `./` or `../../` is how you find your files.

Check out this link for more on how to handle es6 modules.

https://learnersbucket.com/tutorials/es6/es6-modules/

Comment: Thats not a problem ,Bro.. Everything is right on folder pathway.. Other than that , some issues are there .. I dont know what